# Задание написать программу с функцией zip, я написал ее без zip, помогите как-нибудь ее использовать

Tags: python

Вводится строка из слов, записанных через пробел. Необходимо на их основе
составить таблицу из N столбцов и N строк. Лишние слова отбросить. Реализовать
программу с использованием функции zip. Результат отобразить на экране в виде
таблицы из слов, записанных через пробел (в каждой строчке)
Сама программа:

```
import math 
words=[(x) for x in str(input()).split()]
N=int(math.sqrt(len(words)))
columns =[]
for i in range(N):
    columns.append(words[0:N])
    del words[0:N]
for i in range(N):
    print (columns[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

N не надо вычислять оно дано, допустим (чтоб поменьше вводить)
N = 3
Всего в таблице слов
NN = N*N
Функция zip соединяет две последовательности по наименьшей, лишнее отбрасывает
table_words = zip(range(NN), words)
При распечатке в цикле надо сделать отступ между словами по максимально длинному слову. Удачи.